# How do I de-construct HttpResponse?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, akka-http

I want to deconstruct the `HttpResponse` that I get from Server

```
Success(HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Server: akka-http/2.3.12, Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 22:20:21 GMT),HttpEntity.Default(application/json,69,akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@52ffaba9),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1)))
```

I looked at [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/index.html#akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse), but I am not sure how do I deconstruct it

The way I am trying it is

```
 val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
        Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:8080"))

      responseFuture onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
            log.info("response received {}", response)
            log.info("notified about EC Failure")
        }
```

But I am not sure what is the effective way to pattern match on it

Answer (score 2):

Deal with futures as you would an other monadic type in Scala... `map`, `flatMap`, `forEach` and friends:

```
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:8080"))

responseFuture forEach { response =>
  log.info("response received {}", response)
  log.info("notified about EC Failure")
}

// or

for(response <- responseFuture) {
  log.info("response received {}", response)
  log.info("notified about EC Failure")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
responseFuture onComplete {
  case (Success(HttpResponse(statusCode, header, entity, protocol)), _) =>
    log.info("Request returned status code {} with entity {}", statusCode, entity)
  case (Failure(response), _) =>
    log.info("Request failed with response {}", response)
}
```

You can handle specific status codes by matching with `akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes` and adding more cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the type inside of `Success` which is an `HttpResponse` and assign a it to a variable that you can use in the pattern match block. If `Success` contains an `HttpResponse` it is assigned to the variable `hr`, then we can access the methods on the class `HttpResponse` with `hr`.

```
    case Success(hr:HttpResponse) =>
        log.info("HTTP code: " + hr.status)
    }
```